# ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler returns null but I do have a JDK installed

Tags: java

I would like to deploy one of my Java applications to end-users. This application makes use of `ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler()`. I know this function returns null when a JDK has not been installed. This is obviously never a problem for me when working under Eclipse.

To this end, I have therefore asked my users to

- make sure JREs/JDKs have been completed uninstalled from their system
- install Java JDK 8.

When they run my application, however, they **still** get an error saying `ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler()` returns null. I suspect, while they did follow the installation procedure, that the default JRE is the one in the 'jre' directory, not 'jdk'. This is the just the way the JDK installer works (!)

We're on Windows.

My question is: what are they supposed to do to make things work on a permanent basis on their system? I tried having them define a JAVA_HOME environment variable and set to the 'jdk' folder, to no avail (even after a reboot).

I've searched the forum, but all suggestions I get are fairly messy, asking users to run the JAR file from the command line, explicitly calling the JDK's java.exe, which I do not want for my users.

Comment: Copy `tools.jar` located in [JDK1.8]\lib to [JRE1.8]\lib to make it available to your application.

Comment: Can I ship tools.jar directly in my application JAR? If I do ship the tools.jar file of JDK 8, will it work nicely on computers with JRE 9/10/11+ (not JDK) installed? Won't there be any compatibility issues?

Comment: I don't know, you have to test it. I believe that tools.jar must be in the JRE\lib. One thing is sure, the solution will be messy (like you said) because ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler() was not designed to be used with the JRE.